# rails 3.1: how do activerecord query through series of 3 tables joined by has_one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

User has_one UserProfile which has_one Community.

Given a community_id, I want a list of emails from the Users table.

How do I get a list of all User.email where community_id = 5?

The best I can find (which does work) is:

```
User.select(:email).joins(:user_profile).merge(UserProfile.for_community(5))
```

But it seems brute-force... is there not a way to do something simpler along the lines of this below?

```
User.user_profile.community(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you know what your code does...

If the UserProfile has_one community, then the communities table must have a column titled user_id. That means there is only one User associated with any given community id.

To solve your question, as stated, you could delegate the user method to the user_profile.

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_profile
  delegate :user, to: :user_profile
end
```

Then you could do `Community.find(community_id).user.email`

Hope that helps.

Comment: AFAIK if UserProfile has_one Community, then UserProfile has a field called community_id  -- not the other way around -- right?

Comment: Nope. If ModelX has_one :model_y, then the foreign key model_x_id should be in the model_ys table.

Comment: Thanks for steering me the right direction, that's the source of another problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

I think going from the other direction might accomplish what you're looking for:

```
Community.find("5").user_profile.user.emails
```

Comment: thx, but no that gives error saying user_profile is unknown method for community. user_profiles works, but then user is an unknown method for user_profiles. and .user_profile.users gives same eror (users is unknown method for use_profiles)

Comment: Oh so Community has many UserProfiles and a UserProfile has many Users?